# How can I check the length of a long float? Python is truncating the length

Tags: python, numbers

I have a long float - e.g. 3.2222232546222222222222222222222222222222

When I check to see if it is less than a certain amount through len(str(mynum)), it truncates the amount.

So python defaults my number to 3.222223254622222 when i do str(mynum)

Comment: 3.2222232546222222222.. and 3.222223254622222 are indistinguishable when stored in `float` type. That's why you cannot see any extra digits. The problem is unsolvable as it is.

Comment: You have a long float *literal*, which maps to the same value of type `float` as many other float literals.

Comment: If you need more precision than the standard `float` type, see the `decimal` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: The problem with Decimal is that it adds on random digits to the end of the number, and I need to test the raw number I'm pulling in to check if it's less than a certain amount of digits. Is there another workaround?

Comment: @VinceStone `x=Decimal('3.2222232546222222222222222222222222222222')` should not be adding any extra stuff. If you're writing `x=Decimal(3.2222232546222222222222222222222222222222)`, your problem is that you've already lost the relevant information by the time the `Decimal` is created.